# How to find sum of odd numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series

how do I find sum of odd number if first term of Arthimetic Progression  is $a$ and last term is $2n+1$.Please explain this.

Comment: What does A.P. mean?

Comment: Arithmetic Progression, I think. @Ayushakj, are you asking about $\sum_{i=0}^n 2i+1$?

Comment: What is $2_{n+1}$ supposed to be?

Comment: @Clarinetist Now I have edited

Answer (score 3):

So, the common difference is $2$
 and the number of terms$(N)$

Then, $2n+1= a+(N-1)2\iff N=?$

So, the sum $$=\dfrac N2(2n+1 +a)$$

Answer (score 2):

$s_n = a + (a+2) + \ldots + (2n+1)$
$2s_n = a + (a+2) + \ldots + (2n-1)+ (2n+1) + a + (a+2) + \ldots + (2n-1)+ (2n+1)$
$2s_n = m (2n + 1 +a )$

$s_n = \dfrac{m(2n+ 1 + a)}{2}$

with $m = \dfrac{2n+1 -a}{2}$

$s_n = \dfrac{(2n+1-a)(2n+ 1 + a)}{4}=\dfrac{(2n+1)^2-a^2}{4}$